# Count multiple columns with Group By and Union All?

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have a query where I want to count the values of 3 columns s, s2 and s3 and use Group By the values of column s?

So far i have made this [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4C1FxXFnt97HkTWhfRXHNx/8)

This will give me the output

```
1 - count 3  
2 - count 3  
4 - count 4
```

This is almost correct but I also want to include the Where clause correct so the count will only be where season = '2018/2019' and round = 34.

The wanted output must be:

```
1 - count 3  
2 - count 2  
4 - count 2
```

Any idea how to edit this query so the Where clause will work in the counted values?

Kinds regards,

Arie

Comment: You drop s2 and s3 if there is no s in the season and round - I'm curious as to why?

Comment: Because I only want to do the Group By over the values of column s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expand the unioned queries to include season and round and add conditions in the where clause:

```
SELECT t.s, COUNT(*) as count FROM (
    SELECT s, season, round FROM tablename UNION all
    SELECT s2, season, round FROM tablename UNION all
    SELECT s3, season, round FROM tablename
) as t 
WHERE 
  t.s IN (
    SELECT s FROM tablename
    WHERE season = '2018/2019' 
      AND round = 34
      AND s is not null
  )
  AND t.season = '2018/2019' 
  AND t.round = 34
  AND t.s is not null
GROUP BY t.s
ORDER BY count DESC, t.s
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4C1FxXFnt97HkTWhfRXHNx/13).
Results:

```
| s   | count |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | 3     |
| 2   | 2     |
| 4   | 2     |
```

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the rows  for each table in union

```
SELECT t.s, COUNT(*) as count FROM (
SELECT s 
FROM tablename 
WHERE season = '2018/2019'  and round = 34
UNION all
SELECT s2 
FROM tablename 
WHERE season = '2018/2019' and round = 34
UNION all
SELECT s3 
FROM tablename
WHERE season = '2018/2019' and round = 34
) as t 
GROUP BY t.s
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: This works fine, the only thing is that now every value is counted but I wanted only column s do the Group By, in this solution the number 3 is counted also.